# JsonConvert not initialising properties when deserializing unless setter is generic

Tags: c#, deserialization, getter-setter, jsonconvert

Why is JsonConvert not able to initialise property values when getter/setter are not the generic/default ones.
For instance, JsonConvert will deserialise the following class (or rather Property "Value") as it should. Say my Json file contains Value = 5, then my deserialised SomeObjectX object, will have its property "Value" set to 5:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

However if I want the setter to be a bit more complicated and do something special, then it won't work. Here is the new class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int MinValue { get; set; }
    public int MaxValue { get; set; }

    private int _value;
    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            // Restrict range to Min/Max
            if (MaxValue < value)
                _value = MaxValue;
            else if (MinValue > value)
                _value = MinValue;
            else
                _value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

For info, here is how I am calling JsonConvert for the deserialisation into objects:

```
SomeClass SomeObjectX = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass>(File.ReadAllText(@"e:\someObject.json"), settings);
```

Is there a way to get that to work?
In other word, if my Json contains an initialisation property "Value" of 10, then I should get "Value" set to 10 when deserialising.

### Edit

Serialised Json file looks like this:

```
{
  "MaxValue": 10,
  "MinValue": 0,
  "Value": 5
}
```

Here is the non initialised object I am getting at runtime (see that "Value" is 0 not 5 as it should):
[image]

Here is a test on how I created my object instance, initialised it, saved it to Json and then deserialised it back into an object:

```
// Create and init object
var param = new SomeClass(); 
param.MaxValue = 10;
param.Value = 5;

// Settings - Not making any difference with or without
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
    ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace
};

// Serialise into Json
File.WriteAllText(@"e:\param.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param, settings));

// Deserialise back into object
SomeClass obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass>(File.ReadAllText(@"e:\param.json"), settings);
```

Comment: Is there a setting in the json package that controls if fields are preferred over properties?

Comment: What do your JSON doc look like?

Comment: @Neil, I am not sure. Just edited question for Json input.

Comment: Your code is working fine on my laptop.

Comment: Works for me too. v12.0.3 of Newtonsoft.Json. What version are you using? Is upgrading a possibility? Could you share the settings you are passing.

Comment: Using 12.03 too

Comment: @Alex - Tin Le I removed the default values for Min and Max values (they should not be there), which is why it works for you. I did not know that it would make it work, duh! I only set default for info.

Comment: @Ryan Thomas, the setter sets _value to 0 when MinValue and MaxValue don't have a hardcoded initialisation value

Comment: Sorry I meant share the settings object you are passing to the deserialize method.

Comment: @ Ryan Thomas, I have added the setting, but makes no difference, see edit. The problem seems to be happening at construction, nothing to do with the Json deserialisation. Value is initialised and then saved as 0.

Comment: @ Ryan Thomas - Actually, the deserialisation really does not work (sorry for the confusion). When deserialising it tried to set up Value before setting MaxValue and therefore sets it to 0 since default of MaxValue will still be 0.

Comment: If `Value` is set before `MaxValue`, this check will set `_value` to 0: `if (MaxValue < value)`. You should probably rethink your class to avoid the temporal coupling between the properties.

Comment: Thanks @julealgon, is there not a way to define the order in which properties get deserialised though?

Comment: To avoid the coupling altogether, I'd recommend passing all 3 values through the constructor, and performing the check there. Then, you make the model itself immutable.

Comment: As for manually ordering, it seems possible using the `[Order]` attribute. https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/758

Comment: @julealgon, ok, I can do it that way suppose.

Comment: @julealgon, I like better the Ordering approach, cool, thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are facing appears to be related to deserialization ordering of the properties. Your original model contains a temporal coupling between the `Value` and `MaxValue` properties, and depending on the order that you set the values, you'll end up with different results on your object.

You should be able to control the deserialization ordering using a `[Order]` attribute on the properties, but I'd recommend instead making your model immutable, and passing all 3 values through the constructor. That way, you also avoid the temporal coupling altogether, which leads to better design.

Comment: Thanks, I have added an answer/example based on your inputs here below. You are welcome to check it and confirm that it is what you meant, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question using julealgon's input.
Set "JsonProperty Order" attribute as per following example ("Value" needs to use highest Order number):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class SomeClass
{
    [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
    public int MinValue { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
    public int MaxValue { get; set; }

    private int _value;

    [JsonProperty(Order = 3)]
    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            // Restrict range to Min/Max
            if (MaxValue < value)
                _value = MaxValue;
            else if (MinValue > value)
                _value = MinValue;
            else
                _value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This way JsonConvert will first deserialise MinValue and MaxValue before deserialising Value.

Or using immutable properties:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    // Constructor
    public SomeClass(int, value, int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
        MinValue = minValue;
        MaxValue = maxValue;
        // Set value after Min/MaxValue
        Value = value;
    }
    public int MinValue { get; }
    public int MaxValue { get; }

    private int _value;
    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            // Restrict range to Min/Max
            if (MaxValue < value)
                _value = MaxValue;
            else if (MinValue > value)
                _value = MinValue;
            else
                _value = value;
        }
    }
}
```